# Transform or convert the column of a data frame in R

Tags: r

In my special case I want to convert the data in data frame column to boolean/logical values depending on a condition. But I think my question could be used for every converstion/transformation own a data frame column?

Example:

```
> sleep
   extra group ID
1    0.7     1  1
2   -1.6     1  2
3   -0.2     1  3
4   -1.2     1  4
5   -0.1     1  5
6    3.4     1  6
7    3.7     1  7
8    0.8     1  8
9    0.0     1  9
10   2.0     1 10
11   1.9     2  1
12   0.8     2  2
13   1.1     2  3
14   0.1     2  4
15  -0.1     2  5
16   4.4     2  6
17   5.5     2  7
18   1.6     2  8
19   4.6     2  9
20   3.4     2 10
> L = sleep$extra < 0
> L
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I want `L` to be a column inside the data frame (or a new one).

Comment: downvote without a comment? my question to stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add a new column named `L` and assign the values (`sleep$extra < 0`) to it.

```
sleep["L"] <- sleep$extra < 0


#   extra group ID     L
#1    0.7     1  1 FALSE
#2   -1.6     1  2  TRUE
#3   -0.2     1  3  TRUE
#4   -1.2     1  4  TRUE
#5   -0.1     1  5  TRUE
#6    3.4     1  6 FALSE
#7    3.7     1  7 FALSE
#8    0.8     1  8 FALSE
#9    0.0     1  9 FALSE
#10   2.0     1 10 FALSE
#11   1.9     2  1 FALSE
#12   0.8     2  2 FALSE
#13   1.1     2  3 FALSE
#14   0.1     2  4 FALSE
#15  -0.1     2  5  TRUE
#16   4.4     2  6 FALSE
#17   5.5     2  7 FALSE
#18   1.6     2  8 FALSE
#19   4.6     2  9 FALSE
#20   3.4     2 10 FALSE
```

or you can `cbind`

```
cbind(sleep, L)
```

which will add a new column (L) to your `sleep` dataframe.

If you want to replace the same column (`extra`) with boolean/ logical values you can assign the values to the same variable.

```
sleep$extra <- sleep$extra < 0


#   extra group ID
#1  FALSE     1  1
#2   TRUE     1  2
#3   TRUE     1  3
#4   TRUE     1  4
#5   TRUE     1  5
#6  FALSE     1  6
#7  FALSE     1  7
#8  FALSE     1  8
#9  FALSE     1  9
#10 FALSE     1 10
#11 FALSE     2  1
#12 FALSE     2  2
#13 FALSE     2  3
#14 FALSE     2  4
#15  TRUE     2  5
#16 FALSE     2  6
#17 FALSE     2  7
#18 FALSE     2  8
#19 FALSE     2  9
#20 FALSE     2 10
```

Comment: And what exactly does this do? Can you explain your solution a little bit?

Comment: @buhtz added explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the column in multiple ways

```
sleep <- within(sleep, l <- extra < 0) (or)

sleep <- transform(sleep, l = extra<0) (or)

library(dplyr)
sleep <-  sleep %>%
  mutate(L = extra < 0)

extra group ID     L
1    0.7     1  1 FALSE
2   -1.6     1  2  TRUE
3   -0.2     1  3  TRUE
4   -1.2     1  4  TRUE
5   -0.1     1  5  TRUE
6    3.4     1  6 FALSE
7    3.7     1  7 FALSE
8    0.8     1  8 FALSE
9    0.0     1  9 FALSE
10   2.0     1 10 FALSE
11   1.9     2  1 FALSE
12   0.8     2  2 FALSE
13   1.1     2  3 FALSE
14   0.1     2  4 FALSE
15  -0.1     2  5  TRUE
16   4.4     2  6 FALSE
17   5.5     2  7 FALSE
18   1.6     2  8 FALSE
19   4.6     2  9 FALSE
20   3.4     2 10 FALSE
```